# Short story, Utopia, ends up with people not reading anymore

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This is a short story I read recently.

An astronaut returns to Earth. While she was away, humanity was transformed, probably genetically, on purpose, to create Utopia. People can't relate to others they don't know in person anymore, so no more generals, dictators etc. As a side effect, they can't read and write anymore. (Why would you write to someone unknown to you? Or read a letter from someone unknown to you?) Also, no more countries or big cities. Everyone lives in villages. At the end of the story, the astronaut's daughter is "normal", so humanity may revert over time.

I am searching for author and title.

Comment: See if one of these rings a bell. https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/StupidityInducingAttack  Look at Perry Rhodan part in literature. (Warning: Tvtropes link!)

Comment: Nope. None of these look right.

Comment: The is a female astronaut who experiences in time dilation in "Shore Leave Blacks" by Etchemendy. Most of the story is about her nervously going to a family reunion, as she expects her son will have aged 40 years while she was away. I don't remember illiteracy in the society, but it's possible - it's been a long time since I read it.

Comment: @Lise med-et-e Andreasen   The society you describe seems more like a dystopia than a utopia.  With nobody caring about people they don't no personally, there will be more crime, though of course the evil things that people do to strangers might be perfectly legal.  Witout reading and writing, science and techology should cease to advance, and  society will make no progress in extending lifetimes and eventally abolishing death.  Witout large governments, who will carry out large projects like deflecting asteroids on collision courses with Earth?  Continued.

Comment: @Lise med-et-e Andreasen   Contnued.  Before indoor plumbing, people used to carry clear water into their houses in containers, and carry dirty water away in containers.  Babies were bathed in small containers of water.  And thus there was an expression about throwing away the baby with the bathwater, meaning to get rid of something good and important while getting rid of something slightly bad.  And it seems to me that  the dystopian society in that story threw out the baby with the bathwater in its transformation.

Comment: This describes the Eloi in _The Time Machine_ pretty well.

Comment: @Lise med-et-e Andreasen I've read this, and it was pretty much as you describe. I can't remember where I saw it, but it was probably less than 10 years ago. Possibly in an anthology by Jonathan Strachan, or one of the Solaris anthologies, or a late Gardner Dozois?